# postgres -w flag breaking systemd

Tags: arch-linux, postgresql, systemd

So I am pretty new to Arch and am having a strange issue. Using `systemctl` I can not start postgresql. Starting postgresql directly with `pg_ctl` works fine and it is even started briefly with `systemctl`.

The systemd unit file created when installing + initializing postgresql on Arch linux contains the ExecStart command of:

`ExecStart= /usr/bin/pg_ctl -s -D ${PGROOT}/data start -w -t 120`

After taking a look at the unit file I noticed a correlation with the failure time and the timeout for the start command. Once I changed the `-w` flag (wait until operation completes) to the `-W` flag (do not wait until operation competes) voila! Everything works perfectly, no more timeouts or failed service starts.

This is great and I can make a modified unit file no problem. I am just wondering if this is a side-effect of some other configuration being botched or is the generated unit file just being incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The `-w` flag works by periodically trying to connect to your server. Of course, anything that prevents a connection to your server will cause `pg_ctl` to think your server is not started yet. So it hangs around, retrying until the timeout you specified. When it times out, it returns a non-zero exit code to `systemd`, and systemd automatically calls the configured `ExecStop` command, effectively stopping your server.

If you're able to connect to your server when you start it manually with `pg_ctl` (i.e. not just see it in `ps -ef`), then it's possible that some environment variable is different (`PGPORT`, `PGDATA`).

Another thing that can cause this is trying to do a recovery or start up a warm standby server. Until the server is all the way ready, it will accept socker connections but will log an error and refuse any queries. If you are pausing at the end of recovery, or doing warm standby, the server will never go all the way to ready.

There may be some useful information in `pg_log` in your `PGDATA` directory. At least that will indicate if the server is seeing but rejecting queries from `pg_ctl`.